# How to access an object property when its key has a colon in it?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON:

```
{
  "foo:bar":"value",
  "key:id":"1234",
  "url":"www.google.com"},
```

How can I get `foo:bar` value in Javascript ?
I can get `myJson.url`value but i can't access to `foo:bar` because of the colon in it.

Comment: That's not invalid JSON; it's perfectly fine: `myJson["foo:bar"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`bracket notation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to access that value,

```
console.log(myJson["foo:bar"]);
```

And your object is perfectly valid.

Comment: Oh, you have a right ! Thank you all !